# HTML5 video doesn't play on iOS 10.2 on iPad 4th generation

Tags: ios, html, video

I met a weird situation. Our iOS app embedded a video in a simple HTML 5 page, and we load it using javascript and UIWebView. It has been working fine until the upgrade of iOS 10.2, and it works fine on all other models of iPads but iPad 4th generation on 10.2. The video just cannot play. The 'play' event never fires. I did some preliminary research. I know iPad 4 is a 32-bit machine. I'm not sure if this has something to do with the weird behavior.

Comment: Hi! same here. I tested with iPhone 5c. Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this might be a relevant answer, but I had a similar situation when trying to play a video using AVPlayer.

It worked perfectly fine previously on iOS 8 and iOS 9, upgrade to iOS 10.2 and it worked on the simulator but not on devices.

Then I came across this link
[h.264 MP4 Playable on iOS 9 No Longer Playable on iOS 10](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/51343)

From reading further, I see the following statements:

> - There has been a changed in how iOS validates video files.
> - In our case, we were encoding h.264 video with mp3 audio codec.
> - iOS 9 had no problem with the video files. iOS 10 does not like them and gave this error when trying to save to the camera roll "Sorry, this type of video cannot be saved to this device"

To fix my error, I just opened the video in Quicktime Player. I then went to File -> Export -> 1080p and then when I used this version of the video, it played in my app using iOS 10.2

Maybe your situation is different, but this helped in my experience.

Comment: Thanks Shawn. We embedded a simple MP4 file in a simple HTML5 page without any javascript involved, and further tested on this issue. There's something wrong on UIWebView to load HTML 5 videos on an iPad 4 under iOS 10.2. The video can play on other models of iPads on 10.2 but iPad 4. The interesting thing is the video does play on an iPad 4 under iOS 10.1.1. We've submitted a bug report to apple.

Comment: @Jay any news on this?